# Retrieve item from custom list

Tags: c#

I've got a few object  A, B and C.

Every of this object has variable "Id". I want to write universal method which return item from List of object (`List<A>, List<B> or List<C>`)

Example:

```
public T GetById(List<A> a, int id){ ..... }
```

EDIT:
Sorry. I ve got problem with acces to  Id properties.

```
 public T GetById(List<A> a, int id)
{ 
foreach(T item: a)
{
if(item.Id==id) // error - dont know about Id properties at the moment
return item;
}
}
```

Comment: What's the question here? Show us what you've tried so far

Answer (score 2):

```
`public T GetById<T>(List<T> list, int id)`
```

---

Or if you want it as an extension method

```
public static T GetById<T>(this List<T> list, int id)
{
    return list.FirstOrDefalut(item => item.Id == id);
}
```

If A,B,C are all derived from the same base class interface I'd also add a where clause to the function -> so to be sure in compilation time that property Id really exists.